# Click on a GeoJson layer feature shown on Python Folium map

Tags: python, folium, mouseclick-event

I have the following code to display a geojson file on a Folium map in python.

```
import folium
import json 

with open("roadway.geojson") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

m = folium.Map(location=[39.945559, -86.503854], zoom_start=10)
folium.GeoJson(
    data= data, 
    name="Network", 
    show=False,
    style_function=lambda x: {"weight":2, 'color':'black','fillColor': 'lightblue',},
    highlight_function=lambda x: {'weight':3, 'color':'black'},
    smooth_factor=2.0,
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['DLY_TOT_VO'],
        aliases=['Daily Volume:'], 
        labels=True, 
        sticky=True,
        toLocaleString=True
    )
).add_to(m)

m
```

What I get from this is a map with the geojson overlay that has lines displayed in black and then if I hover over each line, I can see the value read from `DLY_TOT_VO` in the geojson file as shown below

[image]

I am including this map in my application using PyQt5. What I'd like to do is to actually be able to click on a line and save the value of `DLY_TOT_VO` for that line in a variable. I will then do some further calculations with that value.

Is there a way I can do that? Maybe a click event listener or something like that? Also, *roadway.geojson* can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nq7pT3XJVt5zqNkJwJgR4mCsG4kCIK_z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Since you can get the mouse position, how about the idea of querying geojson to get the desired value from the obtained latitude and longitude. I have not actually done this. The reference is [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.MousePosition)